# how YARN manages endless jobs like Storm

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Couple of days ago Yahoo posted about Storm-on-YARN project http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/storm-yarn-released-open-source-143745133.html that makes possibility to run Storm on YARN.
That's big improvement, however I have two questions regarding to running tasks like Storm with YARN. Tasks like Storm don't have some limit on execution time... I mean, when you run Storm you expect it will work days or months - listen queue or whatever. 
I mean there are set of tasks that don't have limitation in time execution (I'd like to report 0% progress)

1) what's about timeout? regular M/R is killed when it hangs on, how to prevent it? I walked through the code, but didn't find any special code
2) also, MR1 has queue where jobs waited for execution: when cluster finish one job, it picked up next job from queue. What about YARN? if I will push endless Storm-like jobs A, and the job B, will job B be executed?

Sorry, if my questions seem ridiculous, maybe I miss/don't understand something

Comment: If a container is still alive is determined by the heartbeats, not by the counters (e.g. progress) that were emitted.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop's  JobTracker was(is) responsible for both cluster resources and the application lifecycle. YARN is only responsible for managing cluster resources and the application lifecycle is the responsibility of the application.

This change means that YARN can be used to manage any distributed paradigm. MR2 is of course the initial implementation ( map/reduce over YARN) but you can see some other  implementations like the Storm-on-YARN you mentioned or HortonWorks intention to [integrate SQL in hadoop](http://hortonworks.com/blog/moving-hadoop-beyond-batch-with-apache-yarn/) etc.

You can take a look at a library called [Weave from continuuity](https://github.com/continuuity/weave) that provides a simple API for building distributed apps on YARN